# How to use localStorage on Vuejs3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, local-storage, vuejs3

I am a bit confused about localStorage and using it. I have a copmonent **Statistic.vue** which shows modal at the end.

**Statistic.vue**

```html
<template>
 <p class='modal'>{{numberOfGames}}<p>
<template/>

<script>
export default {
    name: "GameStatistic",
    data() {
       return {
            numberOfGames: localStorage.getItem("NumberOfGames")
       } 
    },
    mounted() {
        //this.$store.commit('checkNumberOfGames')
    },
}
</script>
```

**index.js**

```
export default createStore({
  state: {
    currentGuessIndex: 0,
    isWinner: false
  },
  mutations: {
    checkNumberOfGames(state) {
      if (localStorage.getItem("NumberOfGames") === null) {
          localStorage.setItem("NumberOfGames", 1)
      } else if (state.currentGuessIndex >= 6 || state.isWinner) {
          let counter = localStorage.getItem("NumberOfGames");
          localStorage.setItem("NumberOfGames", parseInt(counter)+1)
      }
    }
  },
  actions: {
  },
  modules: {
  }
})
```

**WordRow.vue**

```
// some stuff
watch: {
   submitted: {
      async handler(submitted) {
           //some stuff
           this.$store.commit('checkNumberOfGames')
   }
}
```

My question is that `numberOfGames` in **Statistic.vue** not showing correct number, alfter loading page it shows correct value otherwise it lefts behind by 1.

Comment: The same way as anywhere else. numberOfGames shows the correct number. It's the value you've got in `data`. In case you expected it to be reactive, the expectations are wrong, it physically cannot be. It's a mistake to use setItem INSTEAD of changing `state` in a store. `state` should be the source of data, and it needs to be synchronized with localStorage. The question doesn't mention the store like it's not important. It looks like Vuex and you can use Vuex persistent plugin for that.

Comment: @EstusFlask Can you show by code example please, I am very new to Vuejs

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using the Vue Use library. It has o pretty nice modulo for using Local Storage with VueX/Pinia in Vue.js 3.

https://vueuse.org/core/useLocalStorage/

Answer (score 0):

localStorage is meant only for persisting state across refreshes, it doesn't natively work with Vue's reactivity.  Instead you can save numberOfGames as part of your vuex state and set your data variable to that.  You can still initialize the store variable with the localStorage number.